# Writing in middle of file, without editing it completely

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, filesystems

I want to edit a file. The file contains the following:

`Hello, I am a student from KiiT University.`

What I wish to edit is:
`Hello, I am a Computer Science Engineer from KiiT University.`

I donot want to write the complete sentence again. Rather, since I know the position of student is starting at 15 and ends at 22. So, I can edit from 15 to 22, with 'Compute' and then shift the remaining sentence by 17 to append 'r Science Engineer' followed by 'from KiiT University.'

> I donot want to rewrite 'from KiiT University.'

Also, please relate to contiguous memory allocation.

Comment: What do you mean by rewrite? Shifting the remaining sentence requires you to re-write to the file.

Comment: Shifting itself means, that you need to "write the complete sentence again", at least for everything after "Hello, I am a " (shifting means copying to different memory, means writing the entire thing again). Given that, the best thing you can do is "write everything again after the start", which any "delete the latter part" followed by a "append-to-file with the new tail part" should solve.

Comment: No common operating system provides a way to insert in the middle of a file. You need to read the file into memory, make the changes you want to the variable, then rewrite the file.

Comment: We'll, I suppose following the concept of contiguous allocation, the data of the file is not stored exactly in a series of memory cells. Rather, they are distributed, implementing a linked list, I am trying to exploit this feature and just use the add in middle of the linked list.

Comment: If you are on a special case, you need to put that into your question. If you are using a file format, which by some way allows for fancy tricks, then that's that. Text, like you are giving in your question, in all "to be expected"-cases doesn't.

Comment: Google contiguous allocation, you'll get my point, it is not a special case.

Comment: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse451/98au/Section/ch11/

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is:

```
phrase = 'Hello, I am a student from KiiT University.'
phrase = phrase.replace('student', 'Computer Science Engineer')
print(phrase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use pythons `re` library for this:

```
import re

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    text = re.sub('student', 'Computer Science Engineer', f.read())

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as of:
    of.write(text)
```

Comment: This doesn't change the file. It doesn't change anything, since you don't assign the result anywhere.

Comment: I need it for editing the file. Regex doesn't write to files.

Comment: Correct, I'm not writing the entire program, I'm only showing how to change the text

Comment: Try to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457014/writing-in-middle-of-file-without-editing-it-completely#comment112211182_63457014